# How to solve the following problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the following ODE? $$y′ − y = 2x − 3;\ y(0) = 1$$

Comment: This is a first order linear ODE. Compute an integrating factor and you can do this easily.  Look that up in any elementary DE book.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both sides of the ODE by the integration factor $e^{-x}$ to obtain $$e^{-x}y'-e^{-x}y=2xe^{-x}-3e^{-x}.$$
The LHS is the derivative of $e^{-x}y$. So we have $$(e^{-x}y)'=2xe^{-x}-3e^{-x}.$$
Setting up the integration on both sides: $$e^{-x}y=\int 2xe^{-x}-3e^{-x} \, dx.$$

Can you integrate the RHS to find its antiderivative, then solve for $y$? After that, use $y(0)=1$ to solve for the value of $C$ that comes up in your antiderivative.

Comment: Haha we had basically the exact same answer at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You could use an integrating factor $e^{\int -1dx}=e^{-x}$. Then we have

$$e^{-x}y'-e^{-x}y=2xe^{-x}-3e^{-x}$$

$$(e^{-x}y)'=2xe^{-x}-3e^{-x}$$

$$e^{-x}y=\int(2xe^{-x}-3e^{-x})dx$$

And you can integrate the first term in that integration with integration by parts

Answer (score 0):

$y^{'}-y=2x-3$
Which is linear in $y$, So integrating factor$\displaystyle=e^{\int -1~dx}=e^{-x}$

Solution :

$y.e^{-x}=\int(2x-3)e^{-x}~dx+C$ where $C$ is contant of integration